# Prevent xml caching when using document() in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, browser-cache

When I use document to get xml from a diferent source on the client side,  How can I make sure that it retrieves a new version of the xml content?

As an example

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="document('/Data/Messages.xml')/Messages"/>
```

Comment: Do you mean it should refresh within the same transformation or over consequent transformations? I don't think it's possible to have the first case, since the document function is supposed to be deterministic (i.e. it should always return the same result for the same input.)

Comment: I mean subsequent. I have the above call in diferent templates,  the trouble is that even jumping to a diferent page it still keeps the same data

Answer (score 0):

You can't, except by exploiting vendor extensions or loopholes. As specified by W3C, repeated calls on `document()` supplying the same URI are required to return the same document.

You can sometimes get around this by varying the URI, for example adding a query parameter such as `?dummy=23679` to the URI, knowing that it will be ignored. Some products allow you to intercept calls on document() in a callback such as a URIResolver - but this may or may not be called in the case of repeated requests for the same document.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion of using a query parameter and it works